# Input left padding make cursor jump

Tags: html, css, padding

I have basic

*HTML*

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-search" id="searchIcon"></i>//you need to use Font awesome
  <input type="text" id="inputField"/>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#searchIcon{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:14px;
  padding-top:6px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
#inputField{
  padding-left:20px;
}
```

So when I click on that input cursor caret appears first at the left inside input field(ignoring padding) and then jump to the correct position. Is there is a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Pls, post your answer with HTML structure

Comment: What browser are you using?  In IE 11, the cursor appears at the indented position right away.

Comment: Using Chrome, but it must to work on every browser.

Comment: I have added sample code to question. I also noticed that if I run that code in fiddleJS it work as intended. However inside project it "jumps". May be there is something else in code or just so many scripts running that it make it slow to take css properties. But if someone had same issue and managed to fix it, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @maximelian1986 See my answer below for a way to work around your cursor jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to work around that problem.  Since the cursor jumps when you do it that way, enclose the `<input>` in a wrapper so you can have your icon on the left, and the input box next to it.  For all intents and purposes, it will look the same to the user.  That way, you don't need to move the cursor.

See the code below for a working example.  I added a wrapper around the input that you can't see, and changed the `padding` shift to a `margin` shift.  (I used a basic HTML icon as a placeholder for your Font Awesome icon.)

```css
#searchIcon{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:14px;
  padding-top:6px;
  padding-left:3px;
}

#inputField{
  margin-left:20px;
  border: none;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 11em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <i class="fa fa-search" id="searchIcon">&#128270;</i>
  <input type="text" id="inputField"/>
</div>
```